# auto increment of data(int type) which is not Id(identity already used) ASP.NET MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, increment, auto

I am trying to auto increment data, which is not Id, I have used Sql Identity on Id so can't use it anymore. I tried sql sequence to bind data column and it works if I add information from sql via script but it does not work on adding from visual studio. I tried to [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] but it does not work too. I have been searching this topic for 2 days in web but can't find any solution

Comment: Look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079217/how-to-generate-and-auto-increment-id-with-entity-framework

Comment: no, that is on Id and uses identity

Comment: @lekinio, I am looking for this solution as well. Did you find anything? I have a workaround by maintaining a sequence in another table and using it for a non-id column. However, to avoid concurrency, I will need some locking mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this. According to the documentation by Microsoft

> A sequence is a user-defined schema bound object that generates a sequence of numeric values according to the specification with which the sequence was created. The sequence of numeric values is generated in an ascending or descending order at a defined interval and can be configured to restart (cycle) when exhausted. Sequences, unlike identity columns, are not associated with specific tables. Applications refer to a sequence object to retrieve its next value. The relationship between sequences and tables is controlled by the application. User applications can reference a sequence object and coordinate the values across multiple rows and tables.

You can create a sequence using the syntax below:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE OrderNumber  
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO
```

To check how it can be used in MVC, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077461/how-to-get-next-value-of-sql-server-sequence-in-entity-framework) post.

Hope this helps!